# Having issues getting my linked list to work

Tags: c

The function I am using to add a new node to the list, keep getting the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)", I feel like at some point I am referencing the list incorrectly

```
void add(Huff ** head, Huff * current, char x)
{

int found = 0;
```

checking to see if the list is empty, sets new node to head

```
if(current == NULL)
{
    Huff * newItem = malloc(sizeof(Huff));
    newItem->c = x;
    newItem->freq = 1;

    newItem->next = NULL;
    *head = newItem;

}
```

checking to see if the nodes have the same value

```
else
{   while(current != NULL)
    {
        if(current->c ==  x)
        {
            current->freq += 1;
            found = 1;
            break;  
        }   

    }
```

if they aren't, add to the list

```
    if(found == 0)
    {
        Huff * newItem = malloc(sizeof(Huff));
        newItem->c = x;
        newItem->freq = 1;
        newItem->next = NULL;


        current->next = newItem;
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: Well, did you step through the code in the debugger?  What line is giving the fault?  Please show definition of Huff.  We are not mind readers.

Comment: When `x` is not found, it will exit the `while` loop with `current == NULL`. How do you expect `current->next = newItem` to evaluate? `NULL->next` will cause segmentation fault.

Comment: Oh and you are not traversing the linked list in your `while` loop. But I'm guessing it's a copy-paste issue.

Answer (score 1):

After this loop

```
else
{   while(current != NULL)
    {
        if(current->c ==  x)
        {
            current->freq += 1;
            found = 1;
            break;  
        }   

    }
```

`current` can be equal to `NULL` in case if the appropriate node is not found.

As result in this code snippet

```
if(found == 0)
{
    Huff * newItem = malloc(sizeof(Huff));
    newItem->c = x;
    newItem->freq = 1;
    newItem->next = NULL;

    current->next = newItem;
    ^^^^^^^
}
```

there is accessed memory using the `NULL` pointer `current`.

I think you could simplify the function interface declaring it like

```
void add( Huff ** current, char x);
```